# Service Worker Offline when Browser Back (requires Refresh)

Tags: firefox, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My service worker is really simple; just a method for caching fonts, JS, and a few other items to accelerate page performance and reduce data transfer.

However, when live ([example](https://heromuster.com/)) navigating to a second page then using the browser's back button displays the OFFLINE page rather than TRYing first or using the natural browser cache.

Relevant part of SW:

```js
// Clear old caches when activated
self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // Try the cache
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      // Fall back to network
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    }).catch(function() {
      // If both fail, show a generic fallback:
      return caches.match('/offline.htm');
      // However, in reality you'd have many different
      // fallbacks, depending on URL & headers.
      // Eg, a fallback silhouette image for avatars.
    })
  );
});
```

This seems more likely (or possibly isolated to) Firefox (current version 59.0.2).

Comment: The issue that is happening here in Firefox is that when you do the `fetch(request)` in the service worker, it is going through the listener again and again and not stuck in a loop and then the worker is stopped by FF. Also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007878/service-worker-fetch-event-listener-only-works-after-page-reload

Comment: @TarunLalwani That exists (updated question).

Comment: Can you please change the `}).catch(function() {` to `}).catch(function(err) {`, so I can see the error on the site

Comment: @TarunLalwani Done.

Comment: It is a `Failed to fetch request because of network error`, which is kind of weird as such

Comment: Which is why it's saying offline... but I don't know **why**. It just doesn't make sense. Btw, what command in the console did you type to view the error (I'm unclear how to trigger it and get the variable). Just to help me identify any issues in future SWs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Installed FF developer version

[image: FF60]

And it works fine in FF60

**FF60**

[image: Working]

The issue is with FF59.0 it seems

**FF59**

[image: FF59]

So most probably a issue that will be fixed with next update