# Block traffic until service worker is installed

Tags: javascript, html

i need to proxy some URLs on my Website. I want to use a Service Worker for it.
When the Service Worker is installed the url rewrite does work fine but when the user visits the Page the first time the url rewrite does not work.

Is there a way to block network traffic until the service worker is installed?

Comment: Service workers are only loaded on page refresh by design. Blocking network traffic wouldn't change this as the behaviour is client-side. For more information on how to properly disable this behaviour, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010127/2744990)

Comment: @JakeBrowning ok i understand. Do you know if there is any other way to do this?
I am trying to make sure that google fonts are loaded from google servers because of a german law. The best idea i had so far is to use service workers and replace the url.